# how to get xpath match assertion value via groovy script?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, groovy, soapui

I have the following output in xpath match assertion in test step1

http://example.com:10010

Test step 2 I have an groovy script to get the previous xpath match assertion value from test step 1.

Is there any function available to get the xpath match assertion value using groovy script ?

Comment: Please show your data and mention what needs to be extracted

Comment: but you can get that value from request/response. Why to get it from Assertion. in assertion things will be constant or are taken from request or response